# Cruise Control error - unversioned file of the same name already exists

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol

Cruise Control couldn't compile a *.sln (or *.vbproj) file because of the error below.  Has anyone ever seen this error before?

**Error:**
unversioned file of the same name already exists

**Cruise Control console error:**

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: Failed to add file '\\dev-web-02\web\lims\dev\docs\UI.Web\web.config': an unversioned file of the same name already exists
. Process command: svn update \\dev-web-02\web\lims\dev\docs --username ccserver --password ccserver --non-interactive --no-auth-cache
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.UpdateSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's probably because someone has deleted the file from subversion and then re-added it, or this file "was" auto-generated (or manually added) on the CC server and now has been added to version control. svn is trying to create that file because it's been added to subversion, but it's erroring because the file is already there.

To fix it, just delete the file at `\\dev-web-02\web\lims\dev\docs\UI.Web\web.config`. The next svn update will get the latest version from the repository.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  It was my fault.  The file used to be named "Web.config" and now it's named "web.config".  Then Cruise Control compiled fine.  How can I avoid this error and still use the name "web.config"?  Before, I deleted the "Web.Config" and committed, and the delete occurred.  then I added "web.config".  I also updated the name of the file in the *.vbproj.  Or does the name have to stay "Web.config" forever?

Comment: IIRC, you can just delete the Web.config from the server and do an "update" using whatever svn client tool is on the server.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I think the RapidSVN client has some handy methods for fixing file case rename issues, but it's been a few years since I last used it.

Comment: We use Tortoise SVN.  That's how I got rid of it actually--deleted the file, then committed.

Comment: I marked this as the answer.  Thanks!  If you know how to rename it to "web.config" with SVN, I'll upvote your comments and answer.  :-)

Comment: Got it figured out... Right click the Web.config file, and choose "Delete and Add to Ignore List". The icon on the file will turn into a red "X". Then commit the change. It will not delete the physical file, but it'll delete it from SVN so it won't commit anymore.